# pyephem set time precedes rise time

Tags: python, pyephem

When I compute the code on the same object, same observer long, lat, I realize ephem returns set time that precedes the rise time for dates before 2014-04-06.

In my code, the sys.argv[1] date is local, is first converted to utc before passing through emphem and returns output after using ep.localtime().

As the output here shows: 
1)the set time on 2014-04-06 is 17:06:10 on 2014-04-05 and the rise time is the same date but 23:16:29.
2) When I ran the code for 2014-04-07, the set time jumps 8 min ahead instead of 4 minutes; but now the set time is consistent with the rise time.

In [13]: run CygArecurazalt.py 2014-04-06

> > > rise:2014-04-05 23:16:29.000005 set:2014-04-05 17:06:10.000005

In [14]: run CygArecurazalt.py 2014-04-07

> > > rise:2014-04-06 23:12:33.000006 set:2014-04-07 16:58:22

Anyone has encountered the same issue? What is the solution to it?
Is there a way such that the rise time (converted back to localtime) is after the sys.argv[1] date (also localtime)?

Comment: Where can we find your `CygArecurazalt.py` script, so that we can see how you are building the object and how you are asking for its rising and setting times?